# Using Facades in bootstrap files in Laravel does not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

It appears that laravel 5 facades (e.g Caching) can only work after the code in bootstraps and config directory finishes running.

So if I have a facades that I want to use in the bootstrap/app.php...then there is no way for me to do that. Right?

Let's say that I want to cache some variable value that takes times to retrieve from API in bootstrap/app.php (e.g determining the target deployment environment on AWS infrastructure) ... then the architecture of Laravel 5.4 would not allow it as per my knowledge and you would have to suffer the performance penalty every time a request is made.

Because please remember that since PHP (Laravel) is essentially stateless, the app.php code (in bootstrap folder) will be executed for your every request.

So there appears to be no way to use any of the Laravel facades like caching to improve performance for every request until you finish the processing of bootstrap code.

> How would you fix the performance impact due to this architecture
>   then? Or are there other ways or strategies to tackle the caching in this scenario since facades are not usable here ?

Comment: Laravel 5 documentation is frustrating at best sometime when it comes to documenting the internal workings of Laravel architecture. It takes a while to figure it out.

Comment: You may be able to cache without using the facade. `$app['Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository']` or `$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository')` may give you an instance of the Cache driver used in your application.

Comment: @ Oluwafemi Sule This sentence will die down the app if used in bootstrap/app.php

Comment: The point is you can register a service early in `app.php`. I however will not advise that approach. You can look to implementing a Cache middleware that does just want you want.